# Java: RuntimeException when run on spoj.com

Tags: java, primes, runtimeexception

Following is the question for prime number generator problem (from spoj.com):

Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!

**Input :**

The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

**Output :**

For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

**Example :**

Input:

```
2

1 10

3 5
```

Output:

```
2

3

5

7


3

5
```

Following is my code for the same:

```
package competitivecoding;

import java.util.Scanner;

class problem2{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);        
    int t = sc.nextInt();   // inputs the "no." of lines that users want to enter
    int a,b, flag, count;
    String line[] = new String[t];
    String[] number=new String[2];

    for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
        line[i] =st.nextLine();
    }

    for(count=0; count<t; count++){
        number  = line[count].split(" ");

        a = Integer.parseInt(number[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(number[1]);

        for(int i=a; i<=b; i++){
            for(int j=2; j<=i; j++){
                if(i%j==0){
                    if(i==j)
                       System.out.println(i);
                    else break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

**Error:** The code when submitted, produces RuntimeException on spoj.com, although it works completely fine on my system.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: .... That is self defining right there.. What number do you think would pop out of ""?

Comment: try "\s+" or use trim() before you split

Comment: Should I put up the complete code for reference?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? More than likely you have a space at the end of one of your lines.

Comment: i think line[i] is not been scanned iteratively..

Comment: i declared a new Scanner object for the integers and it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

```
package abc;

import java.util.Scanner;

class problem2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        int a,b, flag, count;
        String line[] = new String[t];
        String[] number=new String[10];

        for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
            line[i] =sc.nextLine();
        }
        for(count=0; count<t; count++){
            number = line[count].split(" ");}
            a = Integer.parseInt(number[0]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(number[1]);

            for(int i=a; i<=b; i++){
                for(int j=2; j<=i; j++){
                    if(i%j==0){
                        if(i==j)
                           System.out.println(i);
                        else break;
                    }
                }   
        }
    }
}
```

//try this

Comment: what u were trying to do was store a array of string into another without its being declared properly. so what i did was.....declared the string array number in advance. Although i took 10 members it seems i need only a range so u can take 2 members in the string array so as to reduce space occupied during run.

Comment: it has the same problem that I mentioned in my answer. The first line is an "empty" string that holds only the '\n' character.

Answer (score 1):

**Always** handle the exception that can be raised (ideally, any exceptional behaviour that you can recover from, accoding to the Oracle documentation for Exception) and **never** consider user input as safe:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int t = 2;

try {
    /* for each line */
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        /* read the line */
        String line = br.readLine();

        /* split the line */
        String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
        if (numbers.length != 2)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();

        /* parse values */
        int min = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
        int max = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);

        /* do your check */
        __find_prime_numbers__
    }
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    /* notice the user -> input format isn't correct, for example: "1 m" */
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    /* notice the user -> input format isn't correct, for example: "1 " or "1 2 3" */
}
```

Comment: [Swallowing exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding) is not handling them. I'd rather get hit in my face with a srack trace than have the exception swallowed like in your code. *Do* sth with the exception. Log it at least. Don't swallow it.

Comment: If exceptions are due to user input, as in this case, the best thing to do is `catch` them and print out a message for the user.

Comment: @Roadrunner - the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown by me, is handled by the last `catch`. That's because if numbers in input are greater than 2 or is only one, the printed out message, in my code, is always the same. This isn't *swallowing exceptions*. It's just a way to notice the user.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Print the error so we have more info.
You can also do Scanner.nextInt().
Things like multiple spaces , tabs can mess stuff

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `sc.nextInt()` before the first `sc.nextLine()`? because if that's the case, you could have a `'\n'` character in the buffer after using it. So when you use `nextLine()` for the first time, you actually get the `'\n'` character instead of the next line. And when you try to parse to integer it fails.

See here [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

If this is the case, the solution is simple. Just fire a call `sc.nextLine()` that does nothing except to 'eat' that character from the buffer.